# r: install.R returned "execution failed with error code 127"

Tags: r, updates

I tried to update R using:

```
install.R(keep_install_file=TRUE)
```

but I got:

```
The file was downloaded successfully into:
 C:\Users\goubegou\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8wqvhS/R-3.5.1-win.exe 

>Running the installer now...

>[1] FALSE

>Warning messages:

>1: running command ' /c C:\Users\goubegou\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8wqvhS/R-3.5.1-win.exe'had status 127 

>2: In shell(install_cmd, wait = wait, ...) :
  'C:\Users\goubegou\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8wqvhS/R-3.5.1-win.exe' execution failed with error code 127
```

I can find and run `C:\Users\goubegou\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8wqvhS/R-3.5.1-win.exe` in my computer, but the installer seems unable to do so. Can anybody tell me how to deal with the error? Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update R using the R cosole ?
 I have done it with  R console and it works fine with me , all the old packages are kept and it works fine .